# Kafka per topic retention.bytes and global log.retention.bytes not working

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running a 6 node cluster of kafka 0.11.0. We have set a global as well as a per-topic retention in bytes, neither of which is being applied. There are no errors that I can see in the logs, just nothing being deleted (by size; the time retention does seem to be working)

See relevant configs below:

**./config/server.properties** :

```
# global retention 75GB or 60 days, segment size 512MB
log.retention.bytes=75000000000

log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000

log.retention.hours=1440

log.cleanup.policy=delete

log.segment.bytes=536870912
```

**topic configuration (30GB):**

```
[tstumpges@kafka-02 kafka]$ bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zk-01:2181/kafka --describe --topic stg_logtopic
Topic:stg_logtopic    PartitionCount:12       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:retention.bytes=30000000000
        Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4,5,6 Isr: 4,5,6
        Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 1    Leader: 5       Replicas: 5,6,1 Isr: 5,1,6
        ...
```

And, disk usage showing 910GB usage for one partition!

```
[tstumpges@kafka-02 kafka]$ sudo du -s -h /data1/kafka-data/*
82G     /data1/kafka-data/stg_logother3-2
155G    /data1/kafka-data/stg_logother2-9
169G    /data1/kafka-data/stg_logother1-6
910G    /data1/kafka-data/stg_logtopic-4
```

I can see there are plenty of segment log files (512MB each) in the partition directory... what is going on?!

Thanks in advance,
Thunder

Comment: just as a follow up, to test the per-topic configuration, I set retention.ms on the topic and it immediately cleaned up a bunch of space. So delete retention is working, just not with size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to this via the kafka user mailing list. We were apparently hitting kafka bug KAFKA-6030 ([Integer overflow in log cleaner cleanable ratio computation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6030))

Upgrading to v1.0.0 has fixed this for us!